# Where can i find the definition of graph data structure in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: data-structures, graph, isabelle

There are many other data structures defined in Isabelle/HOL, such as binary tree. I didn't find any definition related to graph data structure in Isabelle/HOL document。Where can i find the definition of graph data structure in Isabelle/HOL?Or how to define the graph data structure in Isabelle/HOL, such as the depth-first traversal of the graph.

Comment: Look for the section "Graph Theory" in the AFP (https://www.isa-afp.org/topics.html). I never used any of the entries in this section myself. Therefore, I can hardly provide any further insight.